# Button OnClick in string variable pass another method

Tags: javascript, html

This code is not working.

```
cellDeleteButton.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Sil' id='btnSil'; class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteRow("+table_id+","+lastRow+")'/>";
```

This is code output :

```html
<input type="button" value="Sil" id="btnSil" ; class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteRow(tblEklenecekListe,1)">
```

I want this to be the output :

```html
<input type="button" value="Sil" id="btnSil" ; class="btn btn-danger" onclick=DeleteRow('tblEklenecekListe',1)">
```

Please help me

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you appending this to an element?

Comment: There is a semicolon `;` which could be breaking things: `id="btnSil" ; `

Answer (score 3):

```
onclick='DeleteRow("+table_id+","+lastRow+")'/>";
```

it's wrong, and not a good way to do that.

try this

```js
const input = Document.createElement('input');
input.type = "button";
input.value = "Sil";
input.id = "btnSil";
input.class = "btn btn-danger";
input.addEventListener('click', ()=> deleteRow(tableId, lastRow));

cellDeleteButton.appendChild(input);
```

let me know if that works.

updated: [image]

Comment: İts a not working ı was added screen shot

Comment: Can you check ss please.Updated on post